# Did I compute this expression with logarithm correctly?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification, logarithms

Let $2\leq e\leq r$ and

$$a_{n,k}=2(e+1)^{2(n+k)-1},$$

$$b_{n,k}=2\cdot[ e+e^2+e^3+e^3(e+1)+e^3(e+1)^2+\ldots +e^3(e+1)^{2(n+k)-4}],$$

$$c_{n,k}=2\cdot [2(e+r)e(e+1)^{2(n+k)-4}+(2(n+k)-4)(e+r)(e+1)^{2(n+k)-5}],$$

$$d_{n,k}=2\cdot [(2(n+k)-3)(e+r+1)e^2(e+1)^{2(n+k)-4}].$$

> > I am trying to compute
> >     $$
> > \lim_{k\to\infty}\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log(a_{n,k}+b_{n,k}+c_{n,k}+d_{n,k})\tag{*}
> > $$

Factoring out, the argument of the logarithm up to my computation is
$$
2(e+1)^{2(n+k)-1}\cdot\left(1+\frac{e+e^2+e^3}{(e+1)^{2(n+k)-1}}+\frac{e^3}{(e+1)^{2(n+k) -2}}+\ldots+\frac{e^3}{(e+1)^{2(n+k)-5}}+\frac{(2(n+k) -3)(e+r+1)e^2}{(e+1)^{2(n+k)-5}}\right)
$$

Putting this into $(*)$, I get for the logarithm
$$
\log(2(e+1)^{2(n+k)-1})+\log\left(\left(1+\frac{e+e^2+e^3}{(e+1)^{2(n+k)-1}}+\frac{e^3}{(e+1)^{2(n+k)-2}}+\ldots+\frac{e^3}{(e+1)^{2(n+k)-5}}+\frac{(2(n+k)-3)(e+r+1)e^2}{(e+1)^{2(n+k)-5}}\right)\right)\\
=\log(2)+(2(n+k)-1)\log(e+1)+\log\left(\left(1+\frac{e+e^2+e^3}{(e+1)^{2(n+k)-1}}+\frac{e^3}{(e+1)^{2(n+k)-2}}+\ldots+\frac{e^3}{(e+1)^{2(n+k)-5}}+\frac{(2(n+k)-3)(e+r+1)e^2}{(e+1)^{2(n+k)-5}}\right)\right)
$$
When now computing $(*)$, the first two summands become
$2\log(e+1)$.

But I am not sure what happens with the other summand. I guess each summand in the argument becomes $0$ for fixed $k$ and $n\to +\infty$, so what remains is $\log(1)=0$, i.e.
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log\left(\left(1+\frac{e+e^2+e^3}{(e+1)^{2(n+k)-1}}+\frac{e^3}{(e+1)^{2(n+k)-2}}+\ldots+\frac{e^3}{(e+1)^{2(n+k)-5}}+\frac{(2(n+k)-3)(e+r+1)e^2}{(e+1)^{2(n+k)-5}}\right)\right)=0.
$$

Hence, $(*)$ really should be $2\log(e+1)$.

Am I right or where did I make a mistake?

Comment: I think unless you re-edit this, it might be complained that this isn't a place to ask "check my answer"?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what is your point.

Comment: I believe have seen a few questions on this site that ask "to check my solution" that have had a negative response from the people who  set the policy on the format of a question. Saying that, I've tried to look up on the policy on this but can't find anything. It may be that I'm incorrect, and if so, apologies.

Comment: Ok, you may be right. But for me it is not unusual to have an answer and then to wonder if it is correct and to ask for comments.